# programmatically sort a gridview that is bound to a dataset (stored procedure)

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, dataset

I have a gridview that on button click binds to a dataset, which in itself is populated by a stored procedure. I am just wondering if there is a simple way to apply sorting to the gridview without having to change any sql?

Comment: I've thought about switching to sqlDataSource but I needed the option to update the gridview with a button - hence programmatically binding it. I've also tried putting the dataset into a dataview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the stored procedure value in any temp data table and then apply sorting on the data table data and bind to gridview .

Comment: yup this is effectively what I have done and it has worked - found a brilliant little tutorial here [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/vikram/archive/2008/04/15/manually-sorting-and-paging-gridview-without-using-datasource-control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void radgvData_SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            GridTableView tableView = e.Item.OwnerTableView;
            e.Canceled = true;
            GridSortExpression expression = new GridSortExpression();
            expression.FieldName = e.SortExpression;
            if (tableView.SortExpressions.Count == 0 || tableView.SortExpressions[0].FieldName != e.SortExpression)
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
            else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Descending)
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Ascending;
            else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Ascending)
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
            tableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(expression);
            radgvData.Rebind();
        }
```

Try this code for sorting.........